# Solr doesn't return all values

Tags: solr

I set up a Solr server for indexing my trending data (4 million records).
When I tested it, it was very fast (0.3 seconds). Then I found that the result looks different to the result I query in MySQL.

In MySQL it gets about 4000 records that belong to a set of user IDs. Then I sort and group them using JavaScript.

Solr return about 4000 records with the same set of IDs. After I sort and group them in JavaScript I found some records are missing (about 10). I then added `'rows': 5000000` to the Solr query and I got the same result as MySQL returns but the time increased from 0.3 seconds to 1.7 seconds.

So I wonder is adding `'rows': 5000000` the only way to make the Solr to return the data I need? If yes, am I doing it right? If not, what else should I use?

Comment: Is the index being updated while you're paginating through it? Are you fetching all 4k results in a single query in your first query as well?

Comment: When you said `paginating` I realized that Solr is a pagination index. So `rows: 5000` should be the first 5000 results. And then that's why it doesn't return all because I have to set `rows:4000000` to get all results I need but it's extremely slow.